# trigger click if radio button changed

Tags: woocommerce, click

I tried to trigger click to update the cart but its not work as its should be. the click trigger after I click two times on same radio
I am not sure what is the problem.

I tried:

```
 $(".wcsatt-options input").live("click", function(evt){
    $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");          
  });
```

And this:

```
$('.wcsatt-options input').on('changed', function (event) { 
   $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
});
And this:
 $('.wcsatt-options input').change(function() {
        $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");  
    });
```

My HTML data is like this:

```
<ul class="wcsatt-options ">
                <li class="one-time-option">
                    <input id="radio-0-37bce" type="radio" name="cart[37bce13499fa2eaf9b025dc9fa99a31b][convert_to_sub]" value="0">
                    <label for="radio-0-37bce">                 
                        One Time buy                    </label>
            </li>
        <input class="parent_1" id="parent_1-37bce" name="parent_1-37bce" data-smth="parent_1" type="radio"><label for="parent_1-37bce">Subscription:</label>           
                   <li class="subscription-option">
                    <input data-parent="parent_1" id="radio-1-37bce" type="radio" name="cart[37bce13499fa2eaf9b025dc9fa99a31b][convert_to_sub]" value="1_month" checked="checked">
                    <label for="radio-1-37bce">                 
                        30 days                 </label>
            </li>
                    <li class="subscription-option">
                    <input data-parent="parent_1" id="radio-2-37bce" type="radio" name="cart[37bce13499fa2eaf9b025dc9fa99a31b][convert_to_sub]" value="2_month">
                    <label for="radio-2-37bce">                 
                        60 days                 </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your function with `.on` should work but with following changes:

```
$('.wcsatt-options').on('change', 'input:radio', function( evt ) {
    $('.woocommerce-cart-form').submit();
});
```

I am not sure why you need this input in your code?
`<input class="parent_1" id="parent_1-37bce" name="parent_1-37bce" data-smth="parent_1" type="radio"><label for="parent_1-37bce">Subscription:</label>`

Comment: Hi Dhaval Shah, Thank you for your answer but Its still not working :(, I have id="parent_1-37bce" bcoz it has 2 sub radio boxes.. something like this: https://imgur.com/pAOHi3H

Comment: Can you share the source of the `form` with the class `.woocommerce-cart-form`? If you are on latest version then update button is changed to `button` element instead of `input`. In above code use `$('.woocommerce-cart-form').submit();` in the second line.

Comment: I have updated the code and checked on my local dev. It's working in Chrome, Firefox and Edge.